# Вопрос по верстке. Не понимаю как сверстать сайт

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

возник вопрос как сверстать этот макет, потому что фотография по середине расположена одновременно и в header, и в section.

Comment: Ну расположена, окей, а проблема-то в чём, что не получается?

Comment: не особо понимаю как ее сверстать, чтобы именно пол фотки было в section, а  другая в header

Comment: Есть тег img, есть background-image в css, если же это динамический график, можно продублировать svg-теги там и тут. Всё ещё не понимаю, с чем у вас трудности возникли

Comment: так если у меня тег будет в header, то тогда фотка будет полностью расположена на синем фоне, а если в section, то, наоборот, на белом. а я не понимаю, как сделать, чтобы 1 фотка была и там, и там, потому что если продублировать, то будут просто 2 одинаковые фотки на 2 фонах

Comment: У вас проблема в том, что header и section пересекаются? Просто наложите section поверх header с помощью отрицательного margin-top или position:relative например

Comment: теперь понял, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вопрос про картинку на фоне, то можно сделать наложение, например, с помощью отрицательного `margin-top`

В примере ниже `margin: -180px auto 8px;` — первый `-180px` задаёт отрицательную границу сверху и тем самым создаёт наложение на предыдущий блок, `auto` задаёт автоматические границы слева и справа и тем самым выравнивает по центру страницы, `8px` граница снизу для красоты, чтобы тень не обрезалась

```css
html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.header-main {
   height: 360px;
   background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiWEK.jpg);
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center center;
   color: white;
}

.header-main > h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

.section-1 {
  /* Вся суть здесь */
  width: 400px;
  margin: -180px auto 8px;

  height: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px black;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<header class="header-main">
  <h1>Добро пожаловать</h1>
</header>
<section class="section-1">
  Привет, мир<br/>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqrem.jpg" alt="" />
</section>
```