# Как поднять блок выше на предыдущий

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтоб следующий блок не много налазил на предыдущий. При position: relative пропадает центрирование. Не могу грамотно сверстать это.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/917220

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать margin-top: -100px;